# A way of describing both setup price and ongoing price in schema.org services

Tags: schema.org

So i'm setting up my `ld+json` structured data, using Schema.org schemas. I am adding products with `Offer`s but they only have a single price parameter.

I also looked at `PriceSpecification` too, but there is only `"range"` and `"price"`.

Should I use 2 `PriceSpecifications` (or 2 `Offers`?) with visibly different names, or is there another option I haven't come across? Don't want search engines to get confused.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple PriceSpecifications. However "typically, only the subclasses of this type are used for markup." [UnitPriceSpecification](https://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification) would be the best fit, or the setup price can be of type [DeliveryChargeSpecification](https://schema.org/DeliveryChargeSpecification).

Alternatively, you can use a single [CompoundPriceSpecification](https://schema.org/CompoundPriceSpecification) with multiple [priceComponent](https://schema.org/priceComponent) properties, each of type [UnitPriceSpecification](https://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification). "The name property of the attached unit price specification for indicating the dimension of a price component"

Comment: Thanks very much! Didn't see DeliveryChargeSpec before, I'll see what Google thinks of it.